# Finding records not in another table, and needing a column from a third table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Ok so say I have three tables as follows:

```
t1    t2     t3
---   ---    ---
id    t3_id  id
name  t1_id  name
      value
```

The rails model is as follows:

```
t1             t2               t3
----           ------           --------
has_many :t2s  belongs_to :t1   has_many :t2s
               belongs_to :t3
```

I want to have a list of rows for each t3.name that does not have a corresponding entry in t2 from t1.  So, if we had the following:

```
t1               t2                       t3
+----+------+    +------+------+-----+    +----+-------+
| id | name |    |t3_id | t1_id|value|    | id | name  |
+----+------+    +------+------+-----+    +----+-------+
| 1  | row1 |    |  1   |   1  |  a  |    |  1 | alpha |
+----+------+    +------+------+-----+    +----+-------+
| 2  | row2 |                             |  2 | beta  |
+----+------+                             +----+-------+
```

For alpha I would want

```
t3.name  t1.name
-------  -------   
alpha    row2
```

For beta I would want:

```
t3.name  t1.name   
-------  -------  
beta     row1
beta     row2
```

How would I do this using Active Record methods?

**Updates**

I got the SQL which will get the results I want, but not sure how to put it into Active Record.

The SQL is

```
SELECT T1.name FROM T1 LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT T2.t1_id FROM T3 JOIN T2 ON T3.id = T2.t3_id
   WHERE T3.id = <id>) AS existing ON T1.id = existing.t1_id
WHERE existing.t1_id IS NULL;
```

I could do the following as well:

```
@settings = T3.find(<id>).t2s
T1.select(:name).where.not(id: @settings.map(&:t1_id)
```

Comment: t1.find(1).t3.select(t1.name,t3.name) will return the values for alpha.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your models are T1, T2 and T3, and the T3 object is @t3:

```
T1.includes(:t2s).where.not(t2s: { t3_id: @t3.id }).references(:t2s)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  That only helps me with getting what 'beta' is missing.

Comment: Edited. Realized shouldn't use inner joins. Does this work?

Comment: Same results. I'm seriously considering folding T1 in T2. The only Active Record way I found is in my updates.